# C# Datagridview - How to organize and set certain column and cell values and save the data in a text file

Tags: c#, text, datagridview

I'm using C3 VS 2012 express. Have a windows form with tab control. 
On one of the tabs I would like to (and have setup) a datagridview (not sure if this is what I should use to accomplish what I need but seems like it would suit - open to other suggestions).
Please refer to the attached picture.
Basically I need to create a text file which will have the settings which are set and selected in the datagridview shown.
[IMAGE REFERENCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYC6s.png)
Currently a user can edit the field (which I would like to keep for some fields
I have marked the areas which I need answers for.
Here goes:

1. How to hide this index from the user and be able to select several computernames to be part of the group name PLUTO.
2. I need user to select a date and time here using datetimepicker.
3. How to make button read as BROWSE and place value in location cell (or same cell)
   EDIT :
   I have a part answer for this.. can place value in location cell now:

   ```
   private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {

       OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

       if (fDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)

           return;

       System.IO.FileInfo fInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fDialog.FileName);

       string strFileName = fInfo.Name;

       string strFilePath = fInfo.DirectoryName;

       string strFullFileName = fInfo.FullName;

       textBox4.Text = strFullFileName;
       //dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = strFullFileName;
       MessageBox.Show(strFileName + ", " + strFilePath + ", " + strFullFileName);
       // Set value for some cell, assuming rowIndex refer to the new row.
       dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = strFullFileName;


   }
   ```
4. Should I rather use an ADD button to allow user to add a new row ?
5. What code is required to remove an entry when user selects one to remove ?
6. Generate will be used to write to the file (Currently using fileappend) but what/how do I specify the element to append  (eg is it colum/row number) easily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved most of this one by lot's of browsing and way too many late nights. 
For number:
2. I decided not to use the date and time as it's just not necessary at this stage
3.A browse button was added using this:

```
//this is for button click event for clicking a cell in DGV
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender,   DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 7)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
            // choose file here
            OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (fDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)

                return;

            System.IO.FileInfo fInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fDialog.FileName);

            string strFileName = fInfo.Name;

            string strFilePath = fInfo.DirectoryName;

            string strFullFileName = fInfo.FullName;


            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = strFullFileName;

            dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
```

4. I managed to add rows using an ADD button using this :

   ```
   private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // add rows DGV
   {


       this.dataGridView1.Rows.Insert("one", "two", "three", "four","etc");

       dataGridView1.Rows.AddRange();

   } //end add rows DGV
   ```
5. To remove rows I used a button and this code :

   ```
   private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != -1)
       {

           foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
           {

               this.dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);

           }

       }
   ```
6. To remove a row I used a button and this code:

   ```
   private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\foo\dgvTextFile.txt");//select name for created text file
       try
       {
           string myTableLine = ""; //variable to hold each line


           for (int r = 0; r <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; r++)//loop through table rows, one at a time
           {
               //now loop though each column for the row number we get from main loop
               for (int c = 0; c <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; c++)
               {
                   myTableLine = myTableLine + dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value;
                   if (c != dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                   {
                       //set a delimiter by changinig the value between the ""
                       myTableLine = myTableLine + ",";
                   }
               }
               //write each line
               file.WriteLine(myTableLine);
               myTableLine = "";
           }

           file.Close();
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Grid Export Complete.All changes saved. Use create to create commands", "Program Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

       }
       catch (System.Exception err)
       {
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
           file.Close();
       }
   }
   ```

I hope this helps someone else who is battling.

On a final note .. This proabably is not the BEST code but it worked for me and I hope that at least it will get you going if you're battling too.